# How do I access functions in the main package?

Tags: go

Per the setup:

```
$GOPATH/
  github.com/ddavison/project/
    subpackage/
      lib.go
    main.go
```

#### lib.go

```
package subpackage
...
func Hello() {
  fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

#### main.go

```
package main
...
func main() {
  ...
}

func DoSomething() {
  fmt.Println("done!")
}
```

From **main.go**, I know that I am able to call `lib.go`'s functions by doing

```
import "github.com/ddavison/project/subpackage"
lib.Hello()
```

But how can I do the inverse, **call a method from `main.go` from `lib.go`**?  How can I call `DoSomething()` from `lib.go`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go's funtions are first-class.  Pass the named function `DoSomething` as a parameter to the lib function.

You'd have a circular dependency if anything else was allowed to reference `main`.

### lib.go

```
package subpackage
...

type Complete func()

func Hello(complete Complete) {
  fmt.Println("hello")
  complete()
}
```

### main.go

```
package main
...
func main() {
  subpackage.Hello(DoSomethign)
}

func DoSomething() {
  fmt.Println("done!")
}
```

Comment: so what would you recommend in replacement?  a shared `utils` file that contains all the shared methods within?

Comment: Also, my syntax is horribly off. I've been away from Go for a little bit now :)

Comment: And on, just pass the function reference into the other library. That's no big deal.

Comment: I think this was just a design flaw on my part.  I initially thougt that maybe since it was in the main package, I could just do `DoSomething()` from lib.go, but nope.  The design that fits me best i think, was just moving `DoSomething()` to `utils/utils.go` and doing a `utils.DoSomething()`

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Just as a future reference: http://play.golang.org/p/R6JWzPpWvr.  Passing funcs around is a pretty core part of Go, you should definitely learn to do it :) Although use the right tool for the job. A refactor is always nice.

Comment: Naming a package util [is usually bad](http://blog.golang.org/package-names#TOC_5.) and a sign you haven't thought out the relationship between functions and/or the parts of your program.